# Meaning of "dug-in" and usage of "off" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The following quote is from a transcript of NBC Meet the Press interview talking about president Trump that he wanted to turn over the vote result:

> And, you know, we've heard from a number of officials that the president is not necessarily fully **dug-in** privately on his belief that this is something that he can actually turn around. But he's fundraising **off** of this.

Could anybody tell me (1) the meaning of "dug-in" and (2) the usage of "off" here? I'm a English beginner, and it would be greatly helpful if you give me a little more details.

Answer (score 1):

"Dug-in" here means "committed to" or "determined on". It is a metaphor from a soldier dug-in in a foxhole or trench to resist attack while staying in place.

"But he's fundraising off of this" means that he is using the events, and his public statements, to raise money. "off of" here means "based on" or "deriving from".